# Cloning onto Western Digital Caviar Green

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, disk-cloning

I am considering purchasing a pair of 2 TB `WD Caviar Green` disks to build a `RAID-1` (using the integrated controller on my `ASUS P6X58D-E`).

Currently, my system (`Windows 7`) is installed on a terminally ill 1TB `Seagate Barracuda` (which is however still able to read after several retries).

Originally, the disk was formatted on `Windows XP` (and served as a non-system disk), later `Windows 7` was installed onto it (without repartitioning and reformatting).

To move the system, I want to clone the disk using `Acronis Disk Director`.

I've heard about some performance problems with `WD` disks introduced by new `4K` sector layout and the "impedance mismatch" between the ways `Windows XP` and `Windows 7` handle these disks.

There are recommendations (like [here](http://hothardware.com/Articles/WDs-1TB-Caviar-Green-w-Advanced-Format-Windows-XP-Users-Pay-Attention/)) to install/remove a jumper and run/not run a certain utility called `WDAlign`, but I'm still not sure whether this applies to my situation.

So the questions are:

1. Can the problems arise from cloning an `XP`-created partition onto a `4K` disk?
2. Should I run any utilities or set any jumpers before/after building the `RAID` or cloning the partitions?

Comment: Green disk will hurt performance more than anything. They are designed for storage, not an OS drive.

Comment: When you installed W7, it wiped all formatting and reformatted the disk in the background.

Comment: @Moab: did it? The disk had some data on it which remained after the install.

Comment: @Moab: are there faster disks which are as quiet as these?

Comment: Oh, you did an upgrade install, so it used the formatting already there and moved XP my documents and other data to a folder on C:. I doubt there are any quieter, but performance will suffer on those disks, you will have to make a choice. Start reading hard drive reviews for 7200rpm disks. You might post your question on the Acronis forums, be sure to state which specific Acronis product you intend to use...http://forum.acronis.com/

Comment: @Moab: I took a drive formatted as `NTFS` with some data on it (but it was not a system drive and no Windows folder on it), plugged it into a computer and installed `Windows 7` onto this drive. Is it what called an upgrade install? As for the choice, I made it, I want quiet disks.

Comment: I did find this post from last year, it says there is a special edition of Acronis that does align the partitions correctly, but only works on WD bard drives..http://forum.acronis.com/forum/15877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another Acronis product to create a Full disk image of the failing drive, when it is done making the image use the built in verification utility to make sure it is a good image.

Once this is done you can experiment with what works and what does not since you have a disk image to work with instead of a clone process which may only work once since the drive is on its last legs.

This software can do images, it also has a boot disc you can make to transfer the image to the raid array from an external USB drive that has the image you made.

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html

I don't foresee any problems moving the image to the new advanced format drive.

Once the image has been transfered, and you have startup problems once you try to boot the new raid array, just do a W7 startup repair, that should get it booting.

Edit:

Western Digital has free software to do what you want. Only works on WD brand drives, (it does not matter what brand the source drive is)

http://support.wdc.com/product/downloaddetail.asp?swid=119

> Acronis True Image WD Edition now supports WD Advanced Format Drives and ensures that all partitions are optimally aligned.

Supporting article
http://forum.acronis.com/forum/15877

.

.

Comment: I don't have any external disks, only the current Seagate Barracuda.

Comment: I did an edit, please read.

Comment: `True Image WD Edition` seems to be what I need, thanks!

Comment: Good luck with the project!